# document.cookie/setCookie not working on Safari and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, setcookie

I am trying to play music from last end point after each page is loaded. This example not working on Safari and IE but working fine on firefox,opera and chrome. Is possible to replace this with jquery cookie plugin and how?

```
<audio preload="auto" src="a.mp3" loop="true" autobuffer autoplay="true">
    Unsupported in Firefox
    </audio>

    <script>

    function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
    {
        var exdate=new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
        var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
        document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
    }

    function getCookie(c_name)
    {
        var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
        for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
        {
          x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
          y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
          x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
          if (x==c_name)
            {
            return unescape(y);
            }
          }
    }

    var song = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
    var played = false;
    var tillPlayed = getCookie('timePlayed');
    function update()
    {
        if(!played){
            if(tillPlayed){
            song.currentTime = tillPlayed;
            song.play();
            played = true;
            }
            else {
                    song.play();
                    played = true;
            }
        }

        else {
        setCookie('timePlayed', song.currentTime);
        }
    }
    setInterval(update,1000);
    </script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [document.cookie not working in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240795/document-cookie-not-working-in-ie)