# document.cookie not working in IE

Tags: javascript, cookies

This example working fine in firefox, opera and chrome but not working/cookie not save in IE.

```
function setCookie(name,value,exdays)
    {
        var exdate=new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
        var value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
        document.cookie=name + "=" + value;
    }

    function getCookie(name)
    {
        var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
        for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
        {
          x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
          y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
          x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
          if (x==name)
            {
            return unescape(y);
            }
          }
    }
```

Comment: How is it "not working"? Are you getting any errors? What exact behaviour are you seeing? And what version of IE, Firefox, etc are you using?

Comment: I am using ie8 and 9, opera 21, chrome 43, firefox 34 and i don't know how to get/see any error on ie but here is my related question bro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231222/document-cookie-setcookie-not-working-on-safari-and-ie @Dai

Answer (score 0):

IE has encoding issues unlike all other browsers, some languages are not encode automatically and are %3F encoded instead.

"%3F" = "?" Sign.

You need to look into your cookie while on IE and check the contents, check whether the file is properly encoded. If not, use it like this:

```
 document.cookie=name + "=" + (encodeUriComponent)value;
```

Comment: What is written in your cookie in IE?

Comment: related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231222/document-cookie-setcookie-not-working-on-safari-and-ie